# NHibernate Bag collection is empty

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a strange plroblem when i try to use NHibernate bag

mappings

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="FMG.APO.Dao.Domain" assembly="FMG.APO.Dao">
    <class name="Constraint" table="rConstraintItems" lazy="false">
        <id name="Id" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
            <column name="ConstraintItemID" sql-type="int" not-null="true"  />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="ConstraintGroup" class="ConstraintGroup">
            <column name="ConstraintGroupID" sql-type="int" not-null="false" />
        </many-to-one>

        <many-to-one name="Fund" class="Fund">
            <column name="FundID" sql-type="int" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="LowerLimit" type="double">
            <column name="LowerLimit" sql-type="decimal" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="UpperLimit" type="double">
            <column name="UpperLimit" sql-type="decimal" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

class

private int id;

```
public Constraint() { }
public Constraint(Fund fund, double lowerLimit, double upperLimit)
{
    this.fund = fund;
    this.lowerLimit = lowerLimit;
    this.upperLimit = upperLimit;
}

public int Id
{
    get { return id; }
    set { id = value; }
}

private Fund fund;

public Fund Fund
{
    get { return fund; }
    set { fund = value; }
}

private ConstraintGroup constraintGroup;
public ConstraintGroup ConstraintGroup
{
    get { return constraintGroup; }
    set { constraintGroup = value; }
}

private double lowerLimit;

public double LowerLimit
{
    get { return lowerLimit; }
    set { lowerLimit = value; }
}
private double upperLimit;

public double UpperLimit
{
    get { return upperLimit; }
    set { upperLimit = value; }
}
```

and

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="FMG.APO.Dao.Domain" assembly="FMG.APO.Dao">
    <class name="ConstraintGroup" table="rConstraintGroups" lazy="false">
        <id name="Id" type="Int32" unsaved-value="0">
            <column name="ConstraintGroupID" sql-type="int" not-null="true"  />
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="PlanID" type="Int32">
            <column name="PlanID" sql-type="int" not-null="true"/>
        </property>
        <property name="GroupDescr" type="String">
            <column name="GroupDescr" length="100" sql-type="nvarchar"/>
        </property>
        <bag name="Constraints" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="all">
            <key column="ConstraintGroupID"/>
            <one-to-many class="Constraint" />
        </bag>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

class

```
 public class ConstraintGroup
    {
 private int id;

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    private int planID;

    public int PlanID
    {
        get { return planID; }
        set { planID = value; }
    }
    private string groupDescr;

    public string GroupDescr
    {
        get { return groupDescr; }
        set { groupDescr = value; }
    }


    protected IList<Constraint> constraints;
    public IList<Constraint> Constraints
    {
        get
        {
            if (constraints == null)
            {
                constraints = new List<Constraint>();
            }
            return constraints;
        }
        set { constraints = value; }
    }
}
```

I have 2 identical data bases(I have repeatedly checked and compare them). the bag is populated om my test database but it is empty on my production database. can somebody help me to figure this out? I am really stuck

Comment: where is the bag in the mapping ?

Comment: sorry about that, I am new to this site. the mapping should show the bag now. thanks for your help.

Comment: mapping seems ok, try to enable the logging at query level to see what is issued to the db

Comment: mapping is fine- y don't you enable logging via log4net and capture the SQL statment generated. Also verify the data on your database i.e. check whether there are constraints mapped to the queired constraint group.

Comment: you may generate sql statments using below link http://www.davesquared.net/2008/01/viewing-sql-generated-by-nhibernate.html